# Как в yii2 сделать консольный контроллер с именованными параметрами?

Tags: php, yii2, консоль

Сейчас контроллер типа

```
public function actionTest($name, $type)
```

Будет вызываться как

```
yii test one two
```

Как сделать так, что бы можно было при вызове контроллера задавать конкретные параметры по их именам?

То есть вызов контроллера должен иметь вид

```
yii test --name=one --type=two
```

Answer (score 1):

В yii2 именованные параметры используются для опций - [yii\console\Controller::options()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-console-controller.html#options()-detail)

Вы можете объявить ваши параметры публичными свойствами контроллера:

```
public $name, $type;
```

И указать ваши параметры к массиве опций:

```
public function options($actionID)
{
    $options = parent::options($actionID);
    if($actionID == 'test'){
        $options[]='name';
        $options[]='type';
    }
    return $options;
}
```

В самом действии использовать свойства объекта:

```
public function actionTest(){
    var_dump($this->name,$this->type);
}
```

И использовать так как вы указали:

```
yii controller/test --name=one --type=two
```